# Error while installing OpenScript Helper Services

Tags: oracle, functional-programming, openscript

Im trying to install Oracle Applications Testing Suite - OpenScript, Helper Services are not getting installed. 
Getting Error when I run this Script -  C:\OracleATS\OpenScript\InatallBrowserHelpers:

WebDom Browser Helper Installation failed!
Cannot save multiuser execution setting for Chrome native in registry under key: "HKLM\software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\oracle.openscript.host"

**Once open Script installed, Trying to run a simple Script, getting this Error:**

oracle.oats.scripting.modules.basic.common.api.helperService.exception.HelperServiceException: Failed to connect to helper service on port 7,979.
    at oracle.oats.scripting.modules.basic.common.api.helperService.exception.HelperServiceException.createFailedToConnectException(HelperServiceException.java:33)
    at oracle.oats.scripting.modules.basic.common.api.helperService.HelperServiceConnector.startConnection(HelperServiceConnector.java:99)
    at oracle.oats.scripting.modules.basic.common.api.helperService.HelperServiceConnector.getConnection(HelperServiceConnector.java:72)
    at oracle.oats.scripting.modules.webdom.api.internal.InternalWebDOMService.onBeforeLaunch(InternalWebDOMService.java:1298)
    at oracle.oats.scripting.modules.browser.api.BrowserService.onBeforeLaunch(BrowserService.java:560)
    at oracle.oats.scripting.modules.browser.api.BrowserService.launch(BrowserService.java:317)
    at script.run(script.java:27)
    at oracle.oats.scripting.modules.basic.api.IteratingVUser.run(IteratingVUser.java:353)
    at oracle.oats.scripting.modules.basic.api.internal.IteratingAgent.run(IteratingAgent.java:801)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:208)
    at oracle.oats.scripting.modules.basic.common.api.helperService.HelperServiceConnector.startConnection(HelperServiceConnector.java:96)
    ... 8 more

[image]

Comment: I am having same problem. Did you solve it? If yes, please share solution.

Comment: Solved it. Just run cmd as Administrator and run InstallBrowserHelpers.bat and we're good to go

Comment: Good, will try.