# Unable to do record a script in Oracle Apps Testing Suite "Failed to connect to helper service on port 7,979"

Tags: oracle

when I'm trying to do record and playback in Open script (Oracle apps testing suite) a dialogue box popped up with the following message

> **"Failed to connect to helper service on port 7,979"**

Can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

M. Awais [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39833725/error-while-installing-openscript-helper-services) says that you should

> run cmd as Administrator and run InstallBrowserHelpers.bat